# Using Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games to prove elementary equivalent

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

The following theorem is Theorem 2.4.6 of Marker’s model theory book.

**Theorem.** Let $\mathscr{L}$ be a finite a finite language without function symbols and let $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ be $\mathscr{L}$-structures. Then $\mathcal{M}\equiv \mathcal{N}$ off and only if the second player has a winning strategy in $G_n(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ for all $n$.

**Question.** Can we extend this theorem for arbitrary finite language?

Comment: Short answer: yes, but you have to change the definition of the game a bit. In addition to Nagese's answer to the duplicate question, you should read Section 3.3 "Games for elementary equivalence" in *A Shorter Model Theory* by Hodges.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you Alex!